# How does pytest create fixtures, or, how to get my yield?

Tags: python, pytest, generator, pytest-fixtures

I have a generator function

```
def foo():
    resource = setup()
    yield resource
    tidy(resource)
```

I'm using this as a fixture

```
@pytest.fixture
def foofix():
    yield from foo()
```

This works fine.

I want to test `foo`

```
def test_foo():
    res_gen = foo()
    res = next(res_gen)
    assert res.is_working
```

but because I tidy up `resource` immediately after I `yield` it, it's not longer available to assert it's working. How then does pytest use `resource` before it's tidied up, and how can I do the same?

Comment: Did you try having `test_foo` *actually use* the `foofix` fixture?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i'm just trying that now, but seeing likely unrelated errors

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah that works, but I'm still curious about how pytest does it

Comment: ... I'm a little confused. If you were expecting this to work *without* having `test_foo` use the fixture, then *what was the intended point* of creating the fixture? Oh, you mean that the question is about *how to do the same thing that Pytest does here*, and is *not actually about* testing, but is purely about understanding generators? (I would say to look at the source on GitHub, but it appears to be quite complex.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah it's about understanding generators. My actual use case is I'm reusing `foo` across multiple projects, but want to export it as a function not a fixture so I can customize it without using pytest, so I tried to test it on its own

Comment: test_foo should run fine. The next() does not call tidy(). Only a subsequent next() will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *test* foo, you have just to call it in your code, not to wrap it in a pytest fixture.

Fixtures are good for values that require some boiler plate to be generated, and, when these values have to be tidyed up *after* the test, in a transparent way to the test - so that the test can consume the value, and do not worry about any boiler plate.

If you want to test the `foo` generator itself, and not just consume its value in a test, there is no sense in wrapping it in a fixture - simply import it, or its module, in the module containing the test function, start the generator by calling it, and then call `next` and catch `StopIteration` if needed.

When you run

```
def test_foo():
    res_gen = foo()
    res = next(res_gen)
    assert res.is_working
```

as a plain Python generator, after calling `next` on `foo()` you will get the resource before it is disposed: execution in the generator is paused at the `yield resource` expression when `assert res.is_working` is executed. Only upon the subsequent call to `next` would the `tidy(resource)` line run.

Actually this is *another* problem in your design: generators do not, in any way, ensure they will run to completion (and therefore finishing your resource) - in a pattern like this, it is up to the caller to call `next` until the generator is exhausted.

It is different when you mark a generator as a pytest fixture - in that case, *pytest* will run the generator again, after the first yield, after the test is gone - but that is a pytest "goodie", since it uses this pattern to start and to clean-up a fixture, not the natural behavior of generators.

The pattern there is close to it is to decorate such a generator with Python's `contextlib.contextmanager` call, and then your generator is transformed into a context manager that can be used as an expression in the `with` command. When the `with` command is over, the generator code bellow the `yield` is executed.

So, maybe you want this:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def foo():
    resource = setup()
    # try/finally block is needed, otherwise, if an exception
    # occurs where resource is used in a `with` block, 
    # the finalization code is not executed.
    try: 
        yield resource
    finally:
        tidy(resource)

def test_foo():
    with foo() as res:
        # here, you have "resource" and it has not terminated
        assert res.is_working
    # the end of the "with" block resumes the generator and frees the resource
    return  # even if it is an implicit return.
```